# Convert code to be reusable in a helper class?

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

I have this reference code that I am trying to convert from being specific only for a single object into a SharingHelper class to be reused across multiple objects. Here is that code

```
    public void updateShares(List<Class_Team_Member__c> updatedMembers, Map<Id, Class_Team_Member__c> oldMap) {
    //Create map of access level for 
    List<Class_Team_Member__c> sharingToRemove = new List<Class_Team_Member__c>();
    List<Class_Team_Member__c> sharingToInsert = new List<Class_Team_Member__c>();
    
    for (Class_Team_Member__c member : updatedMembers) {
        Class_Team_Member__c oldMember = oldMap.get(member.Id);
        if (member.Team_Member__c != oldMember.Team_Member__c 
            || member.Class__c != oldMember.Class__c
            || member.Access_Level__c != oldMember.Access_Level__c) {
            //delete the current sharing record IF there does not exist another Class Team Member that warrants keeping the current record
            //insert a new sharing record IF there does not exist another Class Team Member that gives current or higher access to the user
            sharingToRemove.add(oldMember);
            sharingToInsert.add(member);
        }
    }
    
    adjustSharesForDeletedMembers(sharingToRemove);
    createShares(sharingToInsert);
}
```

I plan to keep an object specific TriggerHandler which then calls the Sharing Helper. This is what I have so far for both of those-

```
    public void callUpdateSharesHelper(List<Class_Team_Member__c> updatedMembers, Map<Id, Class_Team_Member> oldMap) {
    
}
```

SharingHelper

```
    public void updateShares() {
     
}
```

I'm stuck on what arguments I'd need to put into the Sharing Helper and get started with these 2 methods. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
public void updateShares(
    SObject[] newList,
    Map<Id, SObject> oldMap,
    SObjectField[] fieldsToCompare
) {

    SObject[] toRemove = new SObject[] {};
    SObject[] toInsert = new SObject[] {};

    for (SObject newItem : newList) {
        SObject oldItem = oldMap.get(newItem.Id);
        if (anyFieldChanged(oldItem, newItem, fieldsToCompare)) {
            toRemove.add(oldItem);
            toInsert.add(newItem);
        }
    }

    // Later logic needs to be generic too
    genericSharesMethodForRemove(toRemove);
    genericDharesMethodForInsert(toInsert);
}

private Boolean anyFieldChanged(
    SObject oldItem,
    SObject newItem,
    SObjectField[] fieldsToCompare
) {

    for (SObjectField field : fieldsToCompare) {
        if (oldItem.get(field) != newItem.get(field) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and using the types/fields from the question the call would be:

```
Class_Team_Member__c[] updatedMembers = ...
Map<Id, Class_Team_Member__c> oldMap = ...

SObjectField[] fieldsToCompare = new SObjectField[] {
    Class_Team_Member__c.Team_Member__c,
    Class_Team_Member__c.Class__c,
    Class_Team_Member__c.Access_Level__c
};

new SharingHelper().updateShares(updatedMembers, oldMap, fieldsToCompare);
```